# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'groupBy' of undefined"' error in ALL browsers

Tags: wordpress, vuejs2, internet-explorer-11

I have a vue app working in all browser bundled with webpack, but for Internet Explorer, I coded the app manually as much as I can.

I see the following error in browser console.

```
vue.js?ver=5.1.1:634 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read 
property 'groupBy' of undefined"
```

I've already tried adding lodash library but it didn't help.

```
var locationsByCity = _.groupBy(locations, function(location) {
   return location.location_data['prefix-tc_map_city'];
});
```

Scripts are added before the `</body>` in the following order.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'vue', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js' ); // Vue
wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX' ); // Google Maps
wp_enqueue_script( 'es6-polyfill', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.min.js' ); // ES6 Polyfill | Promise fixer for ie 11
wp_enqueue_script( 'es6-polyfill-auto', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js' ); // ES6 Polyfill | Promise fixer for ie 11
wp_enqueue_script( 'axios', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js' ); // Axios
wp_enqueue_script( 'lodash', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js' ); // Lodash


// Local Libs
wp_enqueue_script( 'vue-collapse', plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'ie/js/vue2-collapse.js' ); // Vue Collapse
wp_enqueue_script( 'vue-geolocation', plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'ie/js/vue-geolocation.js' ); // Vue Browser Geolocation
wp_enqueue_script( 'he-js', plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'ie/js/he.js' ); // He.js
wp_enqueue_script( 'geolib-js', plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'ie/js/geolib.js' ); // Geolib.js

// Init
wp_enqueue_script( 'init-js', plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'ie/js/init.js' ); // init.js
```

I expect the output to run smoothly and _.groupBy shouldn't be showing undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by **tried adding lodash library**? How did you add it? It would seem whatever you did does not result in a variable called `_` in the current scope.

Comment: Just updated my answer. init.js is the file which has `_.groupBy`, lodash library is included before init.js

Comment: Check your rendered HTML source and make sure that Lodash is included in the correct position

Comment: Try to use the F12 developer Network tools to check whether the related JS reference load success, and you could also set break point to check whether the '_ ' defined the groupBy function.